# Programming / Flashing DM320007 / PIC32MZ2048EFH144

Tags: flash

I want to flash a hex file (bootloader + application) onto the *PIC32MZ2048EFH144* of a *DM320007* dev board. Sadly, I don't get how to flash a hex to this microchip!

I tried *MPLAB X IDE*. If I create a new "prebuild" project I get two possibilities for the hardware tool:

1. *No Tool*
2. *Simulator*

An USB-cable is connected to J3, the debugging port. The jumper JP2 is set.  Many leds on the board are lighting, including the "Green debug indicator LED (D6)". Do I need to install any driver? My device manager seems not to show a new device if I the board is connected to the PC. Also no driver issue is shown. Why is no hardware tool shown?

I also tried the *Unified Bootloader Host Application*. However I could not start this program. Starting by double click seems to do nothing. Starting it via console I get the following error:

```
java -jar C:\Users\username\Desktop\UnifiedHost\UnifiedHost-1.19.0.jar
Fehler: Hauptklasse toplevel.TopLevel konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
Ursache: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

How do I program this device? Do I have to use the program port J7 which is directly connected to the programming pins PGED2 and PGEC2? Can I use "normal" JTAG-Debugger for this purpose? Do I need to install some drivers? Do I have to power the board through another usb port?

Comment: I see there is a PIC24FJ256GB106, which is the same as the PicKit 3. So I guess drivers are the same... But the device drivers shall show something. I would try to debug things by 1) checking JP2 are populated. 2) Checking power is arriving to the onboard PIC24. 3) Changing USB cable with some other cables.

Comment: Thanks for the PicKit 3 hint! By this I realized that I can program the devboard with the MPLAB IPE which successfully recognizes the board and also programs it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Installation of MPLAB IPE

   1. Download *MPLAB® X Installer* (https://microchipdeveloper.com/ipe:installation)
   2. Run installer, optionally deselect *MPLAB X IDE*, *8 bit MCUs* and *Other MCUs*
2. Connect DM320007 with a Mini-USB-cable at J3 (Mini-USB connector next to USB-A connector) to computer
3. Run *MPLAB IPE*

   1. Select the following configurations

      1. Family: 32-bit MCUs (PIC32)
      2. Device: PIC32MZ2048EFH144 (-> Apply)
      3. Tool: Starter Kits (PKOB) S.No : … (-> Connect)
      4. Hex File: Select Hex-File
   2. Click *Program*, the programming takes about a minute. After programming the log should show: *Programming complete*
   3. Disconnect the board by clicking *Disconnect*

The board should be flashed now.